# Unable to downgrade from windows 10 to windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview

I've attempted to downgrade from Windows 10 to Windows Phone 8.1 ... and somewhere along the way it got an error and now i'm stucked on a red nokia screen. Has anyone tried to completely reinstall the OS on the phone before?

My phone is Lumia 635.

Comment: Did you use the Lumia Software Recovery Tool?

Comment: Yes i've tried both Lumia and Microsoft's tool

Comment: Both tools are unable to connect to my phone :(

Comment: Well for some reason - after a few tries - and spacing them out in a few days - it was able to reinstall it without issues using the windows phone recovery utility.

Comment: Are you having the genuine Windows 10 build?

Comment: Yes i did - it was downloaded via my phone via the insider program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying to restore my phone several times, I was able to reset the phone OS back to Windows Phone 8.1 Cyan on Lumia 635 using the Windows Phone Recovery Tool.

This is url to download the recovery tool -> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-backup-restore

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble when I upgrade. But I reset the phone after the upgrade. Settings> About> Reset. Now everything works.

Comment: This surely helps if you can get your phone to boot up completely but it seems the questioner can't get into the settings.

Comment: Yep - i completely bricked the phone that's why i needed to go to the recovery tool route.